# Convergence of a series, find the sum of a series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Prove that the series is convergent and find the sum of it.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n (-2) ^{-k}3 ^{-n+k} \frac{1}{k!}  \right)
$$

I've tried to do something with calculating this sum with respect to k but without any satisfying result.

Comment: Hint: For convergence, factor out $3^{-n}$ from the inner sum and notice then that you're left with the partial sum of a familiar series.  Then use the limit comparison test.

Comment: Thanks! So then I'm left with:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3 ^{-n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k}3 ^{-k}}{k!} \right)
$$
And is it true that:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k}3 ^{-k}}{k!} = (e)^{-3/2}
$$
???
And if it's true then I have:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3 ^{-n}(e)^{-3/2}
$$
And since constant doesn't affect convergence, I have:
$$
(e)^{-3/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3 ^{-n}
$$

Is it correct?

Comment: No, it is NOT true that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k}3 ^{-k}}{k!} = (e)^{-3/2}.$$  However, it IS true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k}3 ^{-k}}{k!} = (e)^{-3/2}.$$

Comment: But now, does $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k}3 ^{-k}}{k!} = (e)^{-3/2}$$ imply that we can write: 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3 ^{-n}(e)^{-3/2}$$ ??
And then determine that a series is convergent?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have congergence (see Antonio Vargas' comment), you can proceed by exchanging the order of summation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2)^{-k} 3^{-n+k}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{-k} 3^{-n+k}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{-k} 3^k}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^\infty 3^{-n}$$

The inner sum now is $\frac{1}{1 - 3^{-1}} - \frac{1 - 3^{-k}}{1 - 3^{-1}} = \frac{3^{-k}}{1 - 3^{-1}} = \frac{3}{2} 3^{-k}$, so we get
$$\frac{3}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{-k}}{k!} = \frac{3}{2} \exp(-1/2)$$

Comment: Fine, but why we skip $$ 3^k $$
in 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{-k} 3^k}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^\infty 3^{-n} = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{-k}}{k!}
$$

And what is the rule for exchanging the order of summation here?

Comment: The inner sum is $3^{-k}$, so $3^k$ and $3^{-k}$ cancel each other. In exchanging summation notice that $k$ can attain arbitrarily large values, so it should run from $0$ to $\infty$. On the other hand $n$ must always be larger than $k$ in every term (and every such $n$ gives us a unique valid term in the original sum), so it should run from $k$ to $\infty$.